# Unicode (UTF8) string word count in PHP

Tags: php, string, unicode, word-count

I need to have the word count of the following unicode string. Using `str_word_count`:

```
$input = 'Hello, chào buổi sáng'; 
$count = str_word_count($input);
echo $count;
```

the result is

> 7

which is aparentley wrong.

How to get the desired result (4)?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by a "word". For instance, are two hyphenated words one or two "words"? Can "words" contain numbers? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$tags = 'Hello, chào buổi sáng'; 
$word = explode(' ', $tags);
echo count($word);
```

Here's a demo: http://codepad.org/667Cr1pQ

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty regex-based (using Unicode) word counting function:

```
function mb_count_words($string) {
    preg_match_all('/[\pL\pN\pPd]+/u', $string, $matches);
    return count($matches[0]);
}
```

A "word" is anything that contains one or more of:

- Any alphabetic letter
- Any digit
- Any hyphen/dash

This would mean that the following contains 5 "words" (4 normal, 1 hyphenated):

```
 echo mb_count_words('Hello, chào buổi sáng, chào-sáng');
```

Now, this function is not well suited for very large texts; though it should be able to handle most of what counts as a block of text on the internet. This is because `preg_match_all` needs to build and populate a big array only to throw it away once counted (it is very inefficient). A more efficient way of counting would be to go through the text character by character, identifying unicode whitespace sequences, and incrementing an auxiliary variable. It would not be that difficult, but it is tedious and takes time.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this function to count unicode words in given string:

```
function count_unicode_words( $unicode_string ){

  // First remove all the punctuation marks & digits
  $unicode_string = preg_replace('/[[:punct:][:digit:]]/', '', $unicode_string);

  // Now replace all the whitespaces (tabs, new lines, multiple spaces) by single space
  $unicode_string = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]/', ' ', $unicode_string);

  // The words are now separated by single spaces and can be splitted to an array
  // I have included \n\r\t here as well, but only space will also suffice
  $words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $unicode_string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

  // Now we can get the word count by counting array elments
  return count($words_array);
}
```

All credits go to the [author](https://gist.github.com/abhineetmittal/d250083def7c356bbf161ff74444ebcc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to count word. You can try this

```
$s = 'Hello, chào buổi sáng'; 
 $s1 = array_map('trim', explode(' ', $s));
 $s2 = array_filter($s1, function($value) { return $value !== ''; });
echo count($s2);
```